# How do I get Scriptures of Time in Final Fantasy Brave Exvius?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

I have one already but I can't find another, and I need them to upgrade a character. How can I get the other Scriptures of Time?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to collect the Scriptures of Time, and [this](https://exviuswiki.com/Scripture_of_Time) wiki gives a breakdown of how to obtain them

> **Dropped from**
>
> Chamber of Awakening (INT has best drop rate)
>
> Dalnakya Cavern - Exploration - *Goblin Guard*
>
> Lanzelt Estuary - *Pit Fiend*
>
> Kol Badlands - *Balloon*
>
> Zadehl Westersand - *Basilisk*
>
> Zadehl Southersands - *Ghost & Golem*
>
> Lanzelt Lowlands - *Pit Fiend*
>
> Lanzelt Highlands - *Balloon*
>
> Lanzelt Ruins - *Medusa*
>
> Shrine of Decay - *Objet d'Art*
>
> **Stolen from**
>
> Deserted Highroad - *Hunger*
>
> Lanzelt Estuary - *Bas-relief, Goblin Guard, & Pit Fiend*
>
> Kol Badlands - *Balloon*
>
> Zadehl Eastersand - *Basilisk & Footpad*
>
> Zadehl Westersand - *Basilisk*
>
> Zadehl Southersands - *Ghost & Golem*
>
> Lechios Hills - *Footpad & Goblin Guard*
>
> Lanzelt Lowlands - *Pit Fiend*
>
> Lanzelt Highlands - *Balloon*
>
> Wolfsfang Peak - *Bas-relief*
>
> Lanzelt Mountains - *Bas-relief & Shiva*
>
> Lanzelt Ruins - *Veritas of the Dark*
>
> Ballen Passage Entrance - *Basilisk*
>
> **Colosseum Steal**
>
> Level  Rank    Round   Monster
>
> BGN    B       1       Basilisk
>
> BGN    A       1       Balloon
>
> BGN    A       3       Ice Sculpture
>
> BGN    S       2       Goblin Guard
>
> INT    B       2       Dark Wizard

Comment: So chamber of awakening is the best bet. So far I've only made it to the part where finally is lost.